# FakeItEasy A.CollectionOfFake doesn't work

Tags: wcf, mstest, fakeiteasy

I have a simple WCF service that returns a list of `PackagesModel.UnitTypeList` to my ASP.NET MVC 4 controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ContentResult GetUnitType() 
{
    List<PackageModelUnitTypeList> _result = lms_client.GetUnitType().ToList();
    return cmn.SerializeToJSON(_result);
}
```

Here's my test that fakes the return list of my service to the controller.

```
[TestMethod]
public void should_GetUnitType()
{
    // Arrange
    int expected_status_code = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    int expected_list_count = 5;

    var context = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData()), _controller_Packages);
    _controller_Packages.ControllerContext = context;

    // Act
    A.CallTo(() => _lms_service.GetUnitType())
        .Returns(new PackageModelUnitTypeList[]{
            new PackageModelUnitTypeList(),
            new PackageModelUnitTypeList(),
            new PackageModelUnitTypeList(),
            new PackageModelUnitTypeList(),
            new PackageModelUnitTypeList()
        });

    var _getUnitType = _controller_Packages.GetUnitType() as ContentResult;
    List<PackageModelUnitTypeList> _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PackageModelUnitTypeList>>(_getUnitType.Content);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected_list_count, _result.Count);
}
```

I am interested on FakeItEasy's [A.CollectionOfFake](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/creating-fakes/) since it will allow me to easily adjust how many fake list I needed to return. But when I tried it I am getting an error:

[image]

Below is my implementation:

```
A.CallTo(() => _lms_service.GetUnitType())
                .Returns(A.CollectionOfFake<PackageModelUnitTypeList>(5));
```

Can someone please help identify why this happens and how to make this work? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

## UPDATE

Based on [@Blair Conrad's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74027685/8331324) answer, this is what it looks like. I debugged the tests and it indeed returns faked list based on the number I wanted:

```
A.CallTo(() => _lms_service.GetUnitType())
                .Returns(Enumerable.ToArray(A.CollectionOfFake<PackageModelUnitTypeList>(1000)));
```

This is what I need. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `_lms_service.GetUnitType()` returns a `PackageModelUnitTypeList[]`.
`A.CollectionOfFake<PackageModelUnitTypeList>` returns an `IList<PackageModelUnitTypeList>`.
You could convert by calling [Enumerable.ToArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray), likely.